# Replace javascript and check order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to replace line breaks with ","  to every line end up like this `85aacb80-bh00-40e3-813c-5ad62ee93f42,324234,user@gmail.com`

And make sure of the format, the long numbers and letters to be always the 1st, the id "324234" to be the second and email field to be always at 3rd. If some line is not matching the order go get deleted and be writed into another output file.

Though I'm stuck here It doesn't work..

The content of the txt file is this

```
85aacb80-bh00-40e3-813c-5ad62ee93f42
324234
usernine@gmail.com
```

And this is the code I'm trying

```
var neek = require('neek');

var readable = 'messagematch.txt';
var writable = 'outputmessagematch.txt';

neek.unique(readable, writable, function(result){ \\Here I remove duplicate lines
 console.log(result);
});

const replace = require('replace-in-file');
const options = {
 files: 'outputmessagematch.txt',
 from: '\n',
 to: ',',
};
```

Comment: Where are you calling `replace()`?

Comment: What is the error you are having?

Comment: it doesnt work the replace, i want to replace linebreaks with "," and what I said in the description, to check the order

Comment: any help on this?